# hot spot on new roof

Tags: roof

[image: roof hot spot]

I had a new roof put on last fall.  I never noticed any hot spots on my roof until this winter.  I had an inspection after the roof was put on and I was told my insulation looks okay.  When they put on the new roof they closed two lower vents on my roof on the back side.  There are canister vents on the back side near the top.  My soffit covers are solid and I'm planning on adding soffit covers with holes.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is the gable vent on the left edge of the photo (just below the peak) a real vent, or just decorative?

Comment: Are you sure that's a hotspot, or just aerodynamic effects from that corner?  I mean a hotspot would explain the bare patch, but definitely not the *thicker* snow left and below it. That would be wind effects.  Can you check it from a clear roof, while snow is coming down, in the calm?

Comment: It is supposed to be a real vent. I have a large attic space it’s like a half floor with blown in insulation and it’s hard to get into the attic.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that deeper snow below and to the left of the bare area? It's deeper than it is anywhere else in the picture: why?

It's very unlikely that that area was much **better** insulated than the rest of the roof, and so has melted much **less**. Instead, it's almost certainly a wind-carved snow drift, especially when you notice that the deepest spot forms a ridge sloping away from the edge of the roof.

With that in mind, it's pretty clear that your bare spot is just an area where the wind during your latest snow storm either didn't deposit snow or actively removed it. Once the storm was done, the snow has been melting everywhere; this spot was the thinnest, and so has become bare before the rest of your roof.

Summary: nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

It is really rather doubtful that a "hot-spot" on the roof is due to just having the roof shingles replaced. The only scenario that could have had some small effect in this regard would have been if the old roof covering was a stack of three layers of old shingles. For cases where a tear-off was not done before adding a new layer of shingles the added layers could have added some degree of insulating from the inside to the outside.

It is far more likely that, if there was an actual change to the location of "hot-spots" on the roof, it is due to changes in the venting and airflow under the roof surface on the inside. If there is an open air space just under the roof on the inside it is beneficial that there be air flow all along the inside surface extending from the soffits to the roof peak. Cooler outside air that circulates in this manner equalizes the temperature differential through the roof and can prevent snow melt on the roof due to escaping heat.

If that upper corner of the attic space inside your dwelling does not get the same airflow as other areas (as previously described) it could be subject to heating from the inside. The fix is to study how the venting is enabled and improve it if possible. You did already mention in the question that there were venting  improvements that you already know that need to be made including adding vent intakes at the soffits.

There is another possibility that the snow fall that occurred recently in your area was accompanied by wind and the wind currents at the peak just happened to blow away most of the snow in that area.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve actually studied this phenomenon and am rather interested in it.  You have the bare spot because the wind carved what I like to call a blow away point or separation bubble. This happens when the wind blows towards your gable roof at a 45 degree angle and it blows the snow off that spot. The deeper snow towards the bottom of the bubble represent areas where the snow was depositors from that bubble in some delta vortices.

Comment: What is the science behind this phenomenon, Scienceguy?